# Can't resolve getSupportActionBar() method in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity that extends ActionBarActivity and hosts a single fragment shown here:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class CrimePagerActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

When I try to make a call to

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

I get an error saying it cannot be resolved. I tried passing in

```
getActionBar()
```

which produced a NullPointerException error at runtime.
Here is the code in question.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, container, false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        if(NavUtils.getParentActivityName(getActivity()) != null) {
            getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try casting the return of `getActivity()` to `ActionBarActivity`: `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity).getSupportActionBar().....`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Resolved the issue by casting the return of `getActivity()` to `ActionBarActivity`:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by casting to AppCompatActivity :

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("titile");
```

Comment: `ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();`
You are right. When using an `Activity extends AppCompatActivity` you should cast THE ACTIVITY reference using `(AppCompatActivity)`.